# MySQL Constraints/Cascades: Will This Work?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, table-relationships

I have a table - threads - and another - posts.

Each thread is like a subject with the posts being replies. If a thread is deleted, all related posts need to be deleted.

All posts have an id and a thread_id field. Here's what I have, just wondering if this is correct.

```
ALTER TABLE `posts`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_threads`
ADD FOREIGN KEY(`thread_id`)
REFERENCES `threads`(`id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Does this need to be the other way around, or is it just completely wrong all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost correct. You don't need `ADD` before `FOREIGN KEY`

```
ALTER TABLE `posts`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_threads`
FOREIGN KEY(`thread_id`)
REFERENCES `threads`(`id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6330a/1)** that shows `DELETE CASCADE` and `UPDATE CASCADE` in action

Comment: Thanks! And kool, didn't know there was a SQLFiddle.